# Play 2.4 com.avaje.ebean.Model

Tags: playframework, ebean

This is my first post so please be gentle.  I am working through some tutorials for using play.  I am on version 2.4, but the tutorials are using an earlier version.  I followed the guide from the play website for incorporating ebeansin 2.4.

```
My build.sbt

    name := """please-work"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "org.avaje.ebeanorm" % "avaje-ebeanorm" % "6.8.1"
)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
 routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

My application.conf

db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver

```
 db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
# db.default.username=sa
# db.default.password=""
 ebean.default = ["models.*"]
```

My plugin.sbt

```
// Play Ebean support, to enable, uncomment this line, and enable in your build.sbt using
// enablePlugins(SbtEbean). Note, uncommenting this line will automatically bring in
// Play enhancer, regardless of whether the line above is commented out or not.

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

This is the code that uses the library

```
package model;

import com.avaje.ebean.Model;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 * Created by craig.ledgerwood on 18/09/2015.
 */
@Entity
public class Person extends Model {
    @Id
    public String id;
    public String name;
}
```

The most irritating thing is my errors keep changing even without me changing anything.  Originally it was the com.avaje.ebean.Model not available.  But now I am getting

```
NoClassDefFoundError: com/avaje/ebeaninternal/server/ddl/DdlGenerator
```

Please could someone point me in the right direction.  I am hoping to move on and use a postgres db in the future, but I want to get the basics down before moving on and these little stumbling blocks are getting frustrating as im sure its something very simple.

Regards

Craig

Comment: It was actually a very simple problem, my package name wasn't consistent with that of the ebean.default in the application.conf.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following dependency in your *build.sbt*

```
"org.avaje.ebeanorm" % "avaje-ebeanorm" % "6.8.1"
```

And in your *plugins.sbt*, update sbt-play-ebean

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "2.0.0")
```

I have resolved the same issue in Play 2.4.6, please refer to it

Comment: BTW, *com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.ddl.DdlGenerator* has been moved to *com.avaje.ebean.dbmigration.DdlGenerator*

Answer (score 0):

There is an incompatibility between Ebean 6.8.1 and the current play-ebean artifact.

Refer to https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean/issues/53

... and: https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean/pull/56